# Graphical errors when exporting to the web from illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png

I am having problems with graphical errors when i export from illustrator
The problem is small border along the right side of the export, the colors of the line varies from export to export.

first image is the exported image

[image]

second is it zoomed in to reveal the issues on the right border

[image]

Have anyone experienced something similar? it appears on all of my export, no matter if i export small, large, cropped etc..

Answer (score 1):

I think @Max Tokman is right, but you don't need to go through Photoshop.
Just `Edit > Preferences > Units` (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) to switch your General Units to **Pixels**.
Then click your Artboard Tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) from the main tool panel.
[image: Main Tool Panel]
Then in the **Control Bar**, check the following properties:

1. **Reference Point** - One of the four corners must be selected, none of the center marks.
2. **X/Y Coordinates of Ref Point** - Both the X and Y must be whole integers, no decimals.
3. **Width/Height** - Both width and height must be whole integers, no decimals.
   [image: Artboard Properties]
   If the above three properties follow those guidelines, you shouldn't have any strange colors/pixels in your Save for Web or Export output.

Answer (score 0):

Your illustrator object or object group is likely positioned with non-integer or odd (as opposed to even) horizontal coordinates.  My suggestion is to export from Illustrator to Photoshop and finalize image manipulation there.